# Covariances of three Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be jointly Gaussian random variables with zero mean and known variances.

What can we say about $E[XZ]$ given we know $E[XY]$ and $E[YZ]$?

We can definitely get a valid range by requiring the covariance matrix to be positive semi-definite. But is there any more structure?

AFAIK being jointly Gaussian, the random variables have a linear relationship between them. But I think this is already fully used in the positive semi-definiteness, as it guarantees that I can find a Cholesky factorization. Is that correct?

Comment: The relation among the three is only determined by that the covariance matrix is positive semi-definite.